# spring boot run not loading static resources from parent / aggregator module

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have struggled with the below problem for about a week and I cannot find anyone who has the same issue.

I have a Maven project that is built up of several sub-modules as shown below:

```
parent-module
   child A (common library)
   child B (spring boot application - no static content)
   child C (spring boot application - static content and JSP
```

In the integration tests for B and C I'm using the spring-boot-maven-plugin that runs the WAR before the integration tests and stops after the integration tests.

I have no problem to navigate into any of the child modules and perform "mvn verify". However if I'm in the parent module and perform "mvn verify" child A and B will pass but child C will fail since the static content and JSP pages cannot be found.

I think the problem due to the fact that Maven will run the application from the parent module and not from the child module and thus the resources and WEB-INF folders cannot be found by tomcat of some reason.

For example, following command in the parent project:

```
parent> mvn -pl ../childC spring-boot:run
```

Will start child C, but the application won't find the static resources. However following command from the child C module will work fine:

```
childC> mvn spring-boot:run
```

Also, to check that I have not done anything fishy in my own project dependencies I downloaded the [spring boot tomcat jsp example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jsp) and created a parent POM like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>my-parent</name>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <modules>
        <module>../jspsample</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

And I just modified the parent of the spring boot sample pom as below:

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../myparent</relativePath>
</parent>
...
```

Now if I execute following from the parent module

```
myparent> mvn -pl ../jspsample spring-boot:run
```

And open http://localhost:8080 in a we browser I get:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sun Sep 18 20:38:23 CEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp
```

So, it seems that spring-boot:run does not work from a parent module. Does anyone have a workaround for this problem. Is it possible to instruct Maven or spring boot plugin to navigate into the child module before starting the WAR/JAR?

A note is that I recently ported my "standard" spring MVC project to spring boot. Before spring boot I used the tomcat maven plugin instead of the spring boot plugin, and that one was working perfectly fine.